# Pair of rimless prescription titanium glasses : screws fit into frame but strips. Hack to fix?

Tags: eyeglasses

I have a pair of rimless titanium prescription frames. I love it. I want to keep it forever - I know this isn't possible but i'd like to extend the life of the current pair I have. The specific model has been discontinued and I'm stuck with this pair so I need to hack it for longevity. I have another pair of different glasses - but as mentioned, this one is special -its successor is not a fit for me.

Currently the screw fits into the frame itself.

This is a bad design. The screw often strips, and then the arm is loose. I know its titanium, but it strips. Glue is obviously not a option - eyesight regresses and I already need to replace the lenses.

My question, considering that it is titanium, considering what the frame looks like, would it be possible to (and Im really happy to pay someone with a steady hand for this but I'm asking if its possible to) drill a hole right through where the screw is, and then attach a good looking nut on one of the sides (screw one side with nut on other side)?

The idea is to get rid of the thread in the frame that holds the screw -as this is the weak point, and if it ever does break, its simply a matter of getting a new screw and nut.

Does anyone have a better idea of how to get past the problem of the screw fitting into the frame?

[image: Rimless Prescription]

Comment: You keep mentioning the frame, but it looks to me as if the arm of the spectacles is screwed directly into the lens rather than into a frame of any sort, or is that just a trick of the light? Are the lenses glass or other material?

Comment: Is there any reason why a small drop of super glue won't work on the screw to hold it in place?

Comment: Thanks I will find and post a better picture to show how the screws go into the lens. I'd like to be able to unscrew the lenses to put new lenses in therefore not going the superglue route unfortunately

Comment: Super glue isn't permanent, so I would consider it a good product to use for this.

Answer (score 2):

You have the answer, and I've used it. Drilling out the hole is quite easy, since it's just enlarging the hole already there to remove the threads. Use a [tungsten carbide drill bit](http://www.eternaltools.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Tungsten-Carbide-Micro-Twist-Drills.gif) and *hand-hold* the bit -- just a few turns with finger-tips should bore out the threads.

**N.B.** Tungsten carbide is hard but quite brittle, so do not apply *any* force other than gentle twist and pressure. Do not force the bit sideways.

Answer (score 1):

Glue headless screws into the holes in the arm (frame), insert the screws into the holes in the lens (make sure they are long enough to protrude from the other side) and use nuts to hold the lens.

Answer (score 1):

Slip a *thin* piece of wire or shim-stock foil into the hole of the frame and replace the present screw. The foil or wire will distort and take up the slack allowing the screw to hold.

Alternately, if the screw is stripped, use a stainless screw with the same diameter and screw pitch to replace it.